# App exits without error when calling method from Media Foundation Interface COM in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, com-interop, hresult, win-universal-app

I've been on a quest for a while now to pass the PCM of an MP3 from W8.1/WP8.1 to Unity3D and I believe I'm getting close. I was referred to [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/459453/Code-to-stream-or-convert-MP-WMA-to-PCM-WAV-in-Wi) which works absolutely fine but, of course, it's in VB.NET so it can't be used with Unity. VB and C# are fairly similar so I set out to translate it. You can see my translation [at this pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/L1ad6wn3)

The problem occurs on line 97. The app simply exits with absolutely no indication of what went wrong. Calling any non-inherited function on the interfaces IMFSample and IMFMediaType has the same effect.

A friend suggested getting the HRESULTs from these functions to see if anything shows up. Google shows getting HRESULTs from COM interops in C# is.. hard. I experimented by changing IMFSample.GetSampleFlags to

```
int GetSampleFlags(out int pRetVal);
```

And that returned "The requested attribute was not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36E6)" and I'm not really sure what to do with that information...

So, I humbly ask you all... just... just what? What do I do from here?

**--- SOLUTION ---**

So as it turns out the solution was a little dumber than I expected.

I did not know this, but apparently COM interfaces that inherit from other COM interfaces have to include ALL of the methods from the parent COMs. Otherwise windows, it seems, throws a hissy fit.

That was it... it was my own laziness in the first place that killed me.

Comment: are you runing your application on x64 Machine?
if do, compile your code in x86 and not "any cpu".

Comment: @TomerKlein That didn't have any effect, sadly =(

Comment: have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411737/media-foundation-imfsinkwriterfinalize-method-fails-under-windows-7-when-mux

Comment: Nope, I... I fixed it. No worries. Thanks for trying to help me anyway. I appreciate it =)