# Record and Playback Video in a byte format

Tags: media, ms-media-foundation

Exactly as it is explained in the title I need to have an application that uses Media Foundation and get stream of data in a raw format save it with out any container then play it back.
I need the easiest solution for that I don't want to customize any plugin.

Comment: Why do you want to save it in raw format? If it's a video stream the file could be huge. Instead you could let MF compress and save it for you, such as by using an MP4 container. The other advantage would be that you could then use the MF SourceReaader to play back the stream since MF will understand the container format. MF doesn't understand raw file formats.

Comment: @sipwiz After requirement of the tool I develop I need it in a raw format then demux these frames and display it again(play back),if I used H264 shall this make size less??

Comment: @sipwiz The problem is the video and other raw frames are muxed in a file so that's why I need it  a raw format if there is other format but keep same concept I am open for that I need it finally in H264 Format Please Help

Comment: @sipwiz I can use even IMFMediaBuffer  save its containt and when I get back Parse buffer by buffer and playback it

Comment: If you specify an mp4 file as the SinkWriter destination MF will automatically encode the samples as H264 for you and yes it will be a lot lot smaller than if you save the raw frames as YUV or RGB. There's no problem saving a single video stream to an mp4 file you don't have to include an audio or any other streams.

Comment: @sipwiz I thought that if I have used MFT this will make me get a smaller buffer,btw you  are an excellent person with great experience so plz help me I am really stuck

Comment: @sipwiz that's what I mean from your code if after MFT I try to to save IMFBuffer will I have my desired small buffer https://code.google.com/p/windows-mediafoundation-samples/source/browse/MFH264RoundTrip/MFH264RoundTrip.cpp

Comment: But saving after the H264 encoder MFT will not make the file any smaller than if you had saved into an mp4 container file. And the BIG disadvantage of saving encoded H264 frames directly to a file is you have to come up with your own scheme to separate the encoded frames. Encoded H264 frames will all be different sizes so you can't relay on a set frmae size as you can with raw YUV or RGB frames. Have a look at this sample https://code.google.com/p/windows-mediafoundation-samples/source/browse/MFWebCamToFile/MFWebCamToFile.cpp is it along the lines of what you're after?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72748/discussion-between-tulipe-and-sipwiz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample below uses the MF H264Encoder MFT to demonstrate how to access the raw bytes from the encoder, full project [here](https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/tree/master/MFWebCamToH264Buffer). The sample does use a SinkWriter to save the encoded samples to an MP4 file but the SinkWriter stage could be removed and replaced by writing to a file directly but then you'll need to come up with your own mechanism for delimiting frames and keeping track of frame duration's and times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <evr.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfplay.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <mferror.h>
#include <wmcodecdsp.h>
#include "..\Common\MFUtility.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplay.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "wmcodecdspuuid.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        const int WEBCAM_DEVICE_INDEX = 1;      // <--- Set to 0 to use default system webcam.
        const WCHAR *CAPTURE_FILENAME = L"sample.mp4";
        const int SAMPLE_COUNT = 25;

        IMFMediaSource *videoSource = NULL;
        UINT32 videoDeviceCount = 0;
        IMFAttributes *videoConfig = NULL;
        IMFActivate **videoDevices = NULL;
        IMFSourceReader *videoReader = NULL;
        WCHAR *webcamFriendlyName;
        IMFMediaType *videoSourceOutputType = NULL, *pSrcOutMediaType = NULL;
        IUnknown *spTransformUnk = NULL;
        IMFTransform *pTransform = NULL; //< this is H264 Encoder MFT
        IWMResamplerProps *spResamplerProps = NULL;
        IMFMediaType *pMFTInputMediaType = NULL, *pMFTOutputMediaType = NULL;
        IMFSinkWriter *pWriter;
        IMFMediaType *pVideoOutType = NULL;
        DWORD writerVideoStreamIndex = 0;
        DWORD mftStatus = 0;
        UINT8 blob[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x42, 0xc0, 0x1e, 0x96, 0x54, 0x05, 0x01, 
                0xe9, 0x80, 0x80, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, 0xce, 0x3c, 0x80 };

        CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
        MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

        // Get the first available webcam.
        CHECK_HR(MFCreateAttributes(&videoConfig, 1), "Error creating video configuation.\n");

        // Request video capture devices.
        CHECK_HR(videoConfig->SetGUID(
                MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE,
                MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID), "Error initialising video configuration object.");

        CHECK_HR(MFEnumDeviceSources(videoConfig, &videoDevices, &videoDeviceCount), "Error enumerating video devices.\n");

        CHECK_HR(videoDevices[WEBCAM_DEVICE_INDEX]->GetAllocatedString(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_FRIENDLY_NAME, &webcamFriendlyName, NULL), "Error retrieving vide device friendly name.\n");

        wprintf(L"First available webcam: %s\n", webcamFriendlyName);

        CHECK_HR(videoDevices[WEBCAM_DEVICE_INDEX]->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&videoSource)), "Error activating video device.\n");

        // Create a source reader.
        CHECK_HR(MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(
                videoSource,
                videoConfig,
                &videoReader), "Error creating video source reader.\n");

        CHECK_HR(videoReader->GetCurrentMediaType(
                (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
                &videoSourceOutputType), "Error retrieving current media type from first video stream.\n");

        // Note the webcam needs to support this media type. The list of media types supported can be obtained using the ListTypes function in MFUtility.h.
        MFCreateMediaType(&pSrcOutMediaType);
        pSrcOutMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
        pSrcOutMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, WMMEDIASUBTYPE_I420);
        MFSetAttributeSize(pSrcOutMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 640, 480);

        CHECK_HR(videoReader->SetCurrentMediaType(0, NULL, pSrcOutMediaType), "Failed to set media type on source reader.\n");

        // Create H.264 encoder.
        CHECK_HR(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CMSH264EncoderMFT, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                IID_IUnknown, (void**)&spTransformUnk), "Failed to create H264 encoder MFT.\n");

        CHECK_HR(spTransformUnk->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pTransform)), "Failed to get IMFTransform interface from H264 encoder MFT object.\n");

        MFCreateMediaType(&pMFTOutputMediaType);
        pMFTOutputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
        pMFTOutputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);
        pMFTOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 240000);
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeSize(pMFTOutputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 640, 480), "Failed to set frame size on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMFTOutputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1), "Failed to set frame rate on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMFTOutputMediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1), "Failed to set aspect ratio on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        pMFTOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, 2);
        pMFTOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE);

        CHECK_HR(pTransform->SetOutputType(0, pMFTOutputMediaType, 0), "Failed to set output media type on H.264 encoder MFT.\n");

        MFCreateMediaType(&pMFTInputMediaType);
        pMFTInputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
        pMFTInputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_IYUV);
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeSize(pMFTInputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 640, 480), "Failed to set frame size on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMFTInputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1), "Failed to set frame rate on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMFTInputMediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1), "Failed to set aspect ratio on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        pMFTInputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, 2); 

        CHECK_HR(pTransform->SetInputType(0, pMFTInputMediaType, 0), "Failed to set input media type on H.264 encoder MFT.\n");

        CHECK_HR(pTransform->GetInputStatus(0, &mftStatus), "Failed to get input status from H.264 MFT.\n");
        if (MFT_INPUT_STATUS_ACCEPT_DATA != mftStatus) {
                printf("E: ApplyTransform() pTransform->GetInputStatus() not accept data.\n");
                goto done;
        }

        CHECK_HR(pTransform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_FLUSH, NULL), "Failed to process FLUSH command on H.264 MFT.\n");
        CHECK_HR(pTransform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING, NULL), "Failed to process BEGIN_STREAMING command on H.264 MFT.\n");
        CHECK_HR(pTransform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_START_OF_STREAM, NULL), "Failed to process START_OF_STREAM command on H.264 MFT.\n");

        // Create the MP4 sink writer.
        CHECK_HR(MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(
                CAPTURE_FILENAME,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                &pWriter), "Error creating mp4 sink writer.");

        CHECK_HR(MFTRegisterLocalByCLSID(
                __uuidof(CColorConvertDMO),
                MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_PROCESSOR,
                L"",
                MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT,
                0,
                NULL,
                0,
                NULL
                ), "Error registering colour converter DSP.\n");

        // Configure the output video type on the sink writer.
        CHECK_HR(MFCreateMediaType(&pVideoOutType), "Configure encoder failed to create media type for video output sink.");
        CHECK_HR(pVideoOutType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video), "Failed to set video writer attribute, media type.");
        CHECK_HR(pVideoOutType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264), "Failed to set video writer attribute, video format (H.264).");
        CHECK_HR(pVideoOutType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 240 * 1000), "Failed to set video writer attribute, bit rate.");
        CHECK_HR(CopyAttribute(videoSourceOutputType, pVideoOutType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE), "Failed to set video writer attribute, frame size.");
        CHECK_HR(CopyAttribute(videoSourceOutputType, pVideoOutType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE), "Failed to set video writer attribute, frame rate.");
        CHECK_HR(CopyAttribute(videoSourceOutputType, pVideoOutType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO), "Failed to set video writer attribute, aspect ratio.");
        CHECK_HR(CopyAttribute(videoSourceOutputType, pVideoOutType, MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE), "Failed to set video writer attribute, interlace mode.");

        // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411737/media-foundation-imfsinkwriterfinalize-method-fails-under-windows-7-when-mux
        CHECK_HR(pVideoOutType->SetBlob(MF_MT_MPEG_SEQUENCE_HEADER, blob, 24), "Failed to set MF_MT_MPEG_SEQUENCE_HEADER.\n");

        CHECK_HR(pWriter->AddStream(pVideoOutType, &writerVideoStreamIndex), "Failed to add the video stream to the sink writer.");

        pVideoOutType->Release();

        //CHECK_HR(pWriter->SetInputMediaType(writerVideoStreamIndex, videoSourceOutputType, NULL), "Error setting the sink writer video input type.\n");

        // Ready to go.

        CHECK_HR(pWriter->BeginWriting(), "Sink writer begin writing call failed.\n");

        printf("Reading video samples from webcam.\n");

        MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER outputDataBuffer;
        DWORD processOutputStatus = 0;
        IMFSample *videoSample = NULL;
        DWORD streamIndex, flags;
        LONGLONG llVideoTimeStamp, llSampleDuration;
        HRESULT mftProcessInput = S_OK;
        HRESULT mftProcessOutput = S_OK;
        MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO StreamInfo;
        IMFSample *mftOutSample = NULL;
        IMFMediaBuffer *pBuffer = NULL;
        //DWORD cbOutBytes = 0;
        int sampleCount = 0;
        DWORD mftOutFlags;

        memset(&outputDataBuffer, 0, sizeof outputDataBuffer);

        while (sampleCount <= SAMPLE_COUNT)
        {
                CHECK_HR(videoReader->ReadSample(
                        MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
                        0,                              // Flags.
                        &streamIndex,                   // Receives the actual stream index. 
                        &flags,                         // Receives status flags.
                        &llVideoTimeStamp,              // Receives the time stamp.
                        &videoSample                    // Receives the sample or NULL.
                        ), "Error reading video sample.");

                if (flags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_STREAMTICK)
                {
                        printf("Stream tick.\n");
                        pWriter->SendStreamTick(0, llVideoTimeStamp);
                }

                if (videoSample)
                {
                        CHECK_HR(videoSample->SetSampleTime(llVideoTimeStamp), "Error setting the video sample time.\n");
                        CHECK_HR(videoSample->GetSampleDuration(&llSampleDuration), "Error getting video sample duration.\n");

                        // Pass the video sample to the H.264 transform.

                        CHECK_HR(pTransform->ProcessInput(0, videoSample, 0), "The resampler H264 ProcessInput call failed.\n");

                        CHECK_HR(pTransform->GetOutputStatus(&mftOutFlags), "H264 MFT GetOutputStatus failed.\n");

                        if (mftOutFlags == MFT_OUTPUT_STATUS_SAMPLE_READY)
                        {
                                CHECK_HR(pTransform->GetOutputStreamInfo(0, &StreamInfo), "Failed to get output stream info from H264 MFT.\n");

                                while (true)
                                {
                                        CHECK_HR(MFCreateSample(&mftOutSample), "Failed to create MF sample.\n");
                                        CHECK_HR(MFCreateMemoryBuffer(StreamInfo.cbSize, &pBuffer), "Failed to create memory buffer.\n");
                                        CHECK_HR(mftOutSample->AddBuffer(pBuffer), "Failed to add sample to buffer.\n");
                                        outputDataBuffer.dwStreamID = 0;
                                        outputDataBuffer.dwStatus = 0;
                                        outputDataBuffer.pEvents = NULL;
                                        outputDataBuffer.pSample = mftOutSample;

                                        mftProcessOutput = pTransform->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &outputDataBuffer, &processOutputStatus);

                                        if (mftProcessOutput != MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT)
                                        {
                                                CHECK_HR(outputDataBuffer.pSample->SetSampleTime(llVideoTimeStamp), "Error setting MFT sample time.\n");
                                                CHECK_HR(outputDataBuffer.pSample->SetSampleDuration(llSampleDuration), "Error setting MFT sample duration.\n");

                                                IMFMediaBuffer *buf = NULL;
                                                DWORD bufLength;
                                                CHECK_HR(mftOutSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&buf), "ConvertToContiguousBuffer failed.\n");
                                                CHECK_HR(buf->GetCurrentLength(&bufLength), "Get buffer length failed.\n");

                                                printf("Writing sample %i, sample time %I64d, sample duration %I64d, sample size %i.\n", sampleCount, llVideoTimeStamp, llSampleDuration, bufLength);
                                                CHECK_HR(pWriter->WriteSample(writerVideoStreamIndex, outputDataBuffer.pSample), "The stream sink writer was not happy with the sample.\n");
                                        }
                                        else {
                                                break;
                                        }

                                        pBuffer->Release();
                                        mftOutSample->Release();
                                }
                        }
                }

                sampleCount++;
        }

        printf("Finalising the capture.\n");

        if (pWriter)
        {
                // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411737/media-foundation-imfsinkwriterfinalize-method-fails-under-windows-7-when-mux for why the Finalize call can fail with MF_E_ATTRIBUTENOTFOUND .
                CHECK_HR(pWriter->Finalize(), "Error finalising H.264 sink writer.\n");
        }

done:

        printf("finished.\n");
        getchar();

        return 0;
}
```